# MYSQL How to count each of the occurrences when there is a OR in the WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

This below query looks simple however i am struggling to understand how to change it, So that

***'when there is appointment and last appointment in the same month' count it as two occurrences (retrieve it as two rows) ?***

```
SELECT *
FROM `assessment`
JOIN `screening` ON `screening`.`a_id` = `assessment`.`a_id`
WHERE   (

            DATE(appointment_date) >= DATE('2022-01-01') and DATE(appointment_date) < DATE('2022-02-01')
                OR
            DATE(last_appointment) >= DATE('2022-01-01') and DATE(last_appointment)  < DATE('2022-02-01')

 )
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the expected results? Also, we don't know which columns in the WHERE clause come from which table?

Answer (score -1):

You can format the date using DATE_FORMAT in a particular pattern 'YYYYMM'. Then use 'in' command. Your query on date lies in January 2022.

```
SELECT *
FROM `assessment`
JOIN `screening` ON `screening`.`a_id` = `assessment`.`a_id`
WHERE '202201' IN (DATE_FORMAT(appointment_date,'%Y%m'),DATE_FORMAT(last_appointment,'%Y%m'));
```